# Docker File - SSL Generation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

While generating an SSL over the Docker File I am getting error:

My Docker File

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-sac2016 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 33684
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-sac2016 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebAPI/DockerRestAPI/DockerRestAPI.csproj", "WebAPI/DockerRestAPI/"]
COPY ["RestModel/RestModel.csproj", "RestModel/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebAPI/DockerRestAPI/DockerRestAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebAPI/DockerRestAPI"
RUN dotnet build "DockerRestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

ENV certPassword "crypticpassword"

# Use opnssl to generate a self signed certificate cert.pfx with password 
$env:certPassword
RUN openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:"crypticpassword" -out server.key 
2048
RUN openssl rsa -passin pass:"crypticpassword" -in server.key -out 
server.key
RUN openssl req -sha256 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj 
'/CN=localhost'
RUN openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key - 
out server.crt
RUN openssl pkcs12 -export -out DockerRestAPI.pfx -inkey server.key -in 
server.crt -certfile DockerRestAPI.crt -passout pass:"crypticpassword"

# Expose port 443 for the application.
EXPOSE 443
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerRestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerRestAPI.dll"]
```

I am getting an error "**openssl : The term 'openssl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or**

I had set the environment path to point the openssl binary , even i tried on the command prompt without the docker file and it works fine , but when using with RUN command its failing always.

Please do advise what wrong I am doing.  My objective is to create and HTTPS for my asp.netcore WEB api

Comment: Can you give more detail about how you're setting the environment path? You might want to try running openssl from the binary location

Comment: Hi @peter , I had set the environment variable using the PATH = c:\openssl\bin where the exe is located. When I am executing openssl.exe from the command prompt it works fine as expected after setting the PATH in the environment variable , whereas its failing when running from the DockerFile

Comment: But is the path set inside your container? Is the openssl binary inside the container?

Comment: @maxm yes its inside the container. So instead of Run I replaced it with CMD and it works fine now.